# Pre-up in the network/interfaces file

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I've been fiddling around with my Raspberry Pi trying to set up Squid as a proxy server.  In the process I have run across a command construct in the interfaces file which I did not know about: ***pre-up***

The exact construct was

```
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.bridge.rules
```

and the /etc/iptables.bridge.rules file was

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
COMMIT
```

OK, that works, but I also have an ebtables command which I would like to run automatically.  I know I can add it to rc.local or other startup files/folders, but I'm wondering it there is a similar construct for this command in the interfaces file?

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6
        --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

Thanks....RDK

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplicity of the task at hand, you may very simply put the following line into `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
pre-up ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6 --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

or you can create an executable file, `/home/my_name/ebtables.rules` with content

```
#!/bin/bash
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6 --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

make it executable, then put the following line into `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
pre-up /home/my_name/ebtables.rules
```

To the best of my knowldege, there are no commands like `ebtables-save` and `ebtables-restore` in Linux. Or better, there used to be, but they have been discontinued because they were broken and no one would support them. [This guy](http://knoffhoff.tumblr.com/post/59967875099/how-to-save-and-load-ebtables-rules) provides his own version of them; IMHO, it's more work than you need to do.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a shot.  I tried googling for pre-up to find out how it works and basically drew a blank.  Is there somewhere where it is documented?  I guess it just basically acts like a command line?

Comment: @RDK45 Search for `pre-up` (multiple references) in this Debian Manual page, https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html

Comment: OK I checked out that reference.  I'm not short on finding examples of the use of PRE-UP, BUT so far I have not found a reference that defines what it is and how it works.  As I said above, it appears to act like a command prompt??

Answer (score 0):

**pre-up** command

Run command before bringing the interface up. If this command fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as configured, prints an error message, and exits with status 0. This behavior may change in the future.

reference this https://manpages.org/etc-network-interfaces/5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).